# Action Script 3. How to avoid collision with background?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, collision-detection, collision

I'm creating simple flash game. I've added collisions for character with walls, stages, etc. But as I see for now collisions are with all objects which I add to stage. When I add background - character can't move (because is collision with background). How to avoid It?

Here is myCollisionList with character (Hero):

```
        var myCollisionList:CollisionList = new CollisionList(Hero);
        myCollisionList.addItem(stage1);
        myCollisionList.addItem(stage2);
        myCollisionList.addItem(stage3);
```

Here is part of code for moving character to left side. When added background I always get trace("Touching wall!"). How to avoid It?

```
     if(left){
                                Hero.x_speed = -walkspeed;
                                setDirection(1);

                                if(myCollisionList.checkCollisions().length > 0) { // checking if is anything in collision list

// I think here is problem, but don't know how to fix It?
             if (hitTestPoint(char.x - 26, char.y+20, true)){ //checking if character touching any object (have collision with anything)

                                    trace("Touching wall!");
                                    Hero.x_speed = 0;
                                }
                                else {
                                    Hero.x_speed = 8;   
                                }}
```

I've tried to use HitTestObject too (but if possible I need to use HitTestPoint)

```
if (Hero.HitTestObject(stage1 || stage2 || stage3)){
.....
}
```

But It works only with first stage1, for other 2 doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your main class is a DisplayObject, otherwise

```
hitTestPoint(char.x - 26, char.y+20, true)
```

would throw an error, as it is testing the point against itself for hits. Since i guess your background is a children of this object, the pixels of the background collide with the point.
Try calling

```
stage1.hitTestPoint(char.x - 26, char.y+20, true)
```

etc...

also

```
if (Hero.HitTestObject(stage1 || stage2 || stage3))
```

is incorrect, i think you are looking for

```
if (Hero.HitTestObject(stage1) || 
    Hero.HitTestObject(stage2) || 
    Hero.HitTestObject(stage3))
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, how can I use this `stage1.hitTestPoint(char.x - 26, char.y+20, true)` in one if? I mean is It possible something like `stage1||stage2||stage3.hitTestPoint(char.x - 26, char.y+20, true)` I know this is incorrect, but maybe is similiar way like this? Or what method is best in this case?

Comment: I have used `private var Hero:hero = new hero; var char:MovieClip = new MovieClip;
    char.x = Hero.x;
    char.y = Hero.y;` so I don't know if this is correct way.

Comment: Yes, hittesting all objects is a simple way if you dont have many obstacles. Keep in mind that if your framerate is high and you have many (hundreds) of obstacles, it may be slow. The correct way is similar to the last block of code in my answer.
Make sure you understand that myDispObj.hitTestPoint and myDispObj.hitTestObject will merely check if the calling object and the parameter overlap, and return a Boolean. Neither will it move or alter anything in any way. I also highly recommend using Capital letters for Classes, and normal ones for variables. ie `var hero:Hero = new Hero()`

Comment: Is it possible to make with hitTestPoint? Because if hitTestobject and jump on this stages I can't move to left or right because It have collision with these stages.

Comment: It will not matter which one you use. You will have to come up with a behaviour to handle collisions. The most basic approach would be to set the characters position upon collision somewhere where it no longer collides. hitTestPoint and hitTestObject are generally very weak for a realistic game engine and usually avoided by developers, who instead create their own collision handling from scratch, or use an already complete engine (which still requires substantial understanding of as3). However, if it is just some simple animation or basic (and not too fast) movement, it will work.